# Permission denied when running redis via java on mac

Tags: java, macos, unix, junit, redis

I am using embedded redis project https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis
trying to run it via my unit testing. I am on mac machine.

My redis impl is on dir: /Users/myname/servers/redis-unstable

as soon as I try to run it:

```
@Before
    public void init() throws IOException {     
        redisServer = new RedisServer(new File("/Users/myname/servers/redis-unstable"), 6379);   
        redisServer.start();
    }
```

I am getting permission denied:

```
redis.embedded.exceptions.EmbeddedRedisException: Failed to start Redis instance
    at redis.embedded.AbstractRedisInstance.start(AbstractRedisInstance.java:42)
    at redis.embedded.RedisServer.start(RedisServer.java:9)
    at com.zone.world_map_service_web.LocationServiceTest.init(LocationServiceTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/myname/servers/redis-unstable" (in directory "/Users/myname/servers"): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at redis.embedded.AbstractRedisInstance.start(AbstractRedisInstance.java:37)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 30 more
```

I tried everything.. did chmod 755 chmod u+x

still same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you run the make command after downloading this?  I would think that even if it was the unstable version, you'd be looking for redis-server and not redis-unstable.

Comment: redis-unstable working just fine and I can work with it. I just got this permission issue when executing it via this java unit testing process

Comment: I may have misspoke, I believe the executable for redis-server is always called redis-server regardless of version (unless you renamed it).  I am finding the executable under ..../redis-unstable/src/redis-server  .

Comment: It's about permissions on mac and I have no idea how to overcome them

Comment: What user does your code run as?  Can you 'su - codeRunningUser' then try running the redis server via command line?